# mathematical statistic question

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, absolute-value

Y~Erlang(n,1) , how to solve E(|Y-n|))?

I think that we have to divide integral by 2 parts, one with y>n, other one with y<n. But I couldn't progress anymore. someone know about this?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the distribution of $Z_j=Y_j-1$, where $Y_j \sim Exponential(1)$, and $Y \stackrel{iid}{=} \sum_j Y_j$, (iid)  then $Y-n = \sum_{j=1}^{n}Z_j$.

Derive the distribution of $Z_j, \ f_{Z_j}(z_j) = e^{-z+1}, z \geq -1$, and find its expectation. Then $\mathbf{E}[Y-n]=\sum_j\mathbf{E}[Z_j]$, because $Z_j$ are also iid.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. It's not just E[Y−n], need to figure out E(|Y-n|). Problem is how to cope with absolute value stuff. By the way, your approach seems smart.

Comment: We are not here to solve your problems for you. You can derive the expression you need if you work from my hint.